# Hibernate Save, Hibernate Rollback

Tags: java, hibernate, commit, rollback

I'm trying to make my DAO work this way:

```
    public void incrementNumber(long id) throws Exception{
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Number n = (Number)session.load(Number.class, id);
        n.setNumber(n.getNumber() +5);
//      throw new IllegalArgumentException("BLAH");
        session.close();
    }
```

1. By commenting out the exception, the update will commit.
2. By un-commenting(?) the exception, it will rollback.

Any way to achieve this? Note: the transaction part is done in a service, under a transactional annotation.

Comment: make it in try...catch something like: try {....do the hibernate stuff...} catch (illegalargumentexception e) {session.rollback();} finally {session.close}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DAO is mainly responsible for persistence operations .It should only provide CRUD and some finder methods relating to a particular entity.

IMO , your method  more like a business operation rather than the persistence operations . As you have the service layer , I suggest you move this method to it.

So , your NumberDAO  may look like this:

```
public class NumberDAO {

     public Number loadById(long id){ }

}
```

And you NumberService may look like this:

```
public class NumberService{

        //Inject by DI containers , or setter / constructor
        NumberDAO numberDAO;

         public void incrementNumber(long id , int increaseAmount) throws Exception{

                Number n = (Number) numberDAO.loadById(id);

                if (XXXXXXXX) 
                    throws new IllegalArgumentException("BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH");

                n.setNumber(n.getNumber() +increaseAmount);
         }

}
```

As you use transactional annotation in the service layer , it  will commit automatically if your service method returns successfully .In case of any exceptions throw before the method returns , the transaction will rollback automatically .

Comment: thanks, I tried this, however, it fails to commit into the database when it does throw the exception... any suggestion on that?

Comment: If exceptions throws , it means  transaction should rollback . If you want to commit the transaction , then you should not throw the exception . What do you want actually?

Comment: To commit when the no exception is thrown, and rollback when exception is thrown. For some reason, the update is not committed into the database even if no exception is thrown.

Comment: It sounds like it is the problem of your transactional annotation . Are you sure it really works?  Beside , please make sure that both the DAO and the service use the SAME hibernate session.

Comment: Well, this is the annotation for the function: '@Transactional(readOnly=false, rollbackFor=DataIntegrityViolationException.class)'

Comment: It seems that you use Spring to manage the transaction . Then your hibernate session in your DAO and service should also be injected by the Spring (i.e  not use `Session session = factory.openSession()` in  the service and DAO) , right?

Answer (score 0):

commit is not always committing to the db, it is setting at the session cache that this has to be committed, then when you will do flush (also depending on the configuration) the commit will go to the DB, or when the session/transaction ends.

So if you want to force it use flush() after commit.
If you can wait check after the session/transaction is being closed.